# What is lastApplied and matchIndex in raft protocol for volatile state in server?

Tags: algorithm, distributed-system, consensus, raft

I am using the following [pdf](https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf) as reference.[image]

It says that `lastApplied` is the highest log entry applied to state machine, but how is that any different than the `commitIndex`?

Also is the `matchIndex` on leader just the commitIndex on followers? If not what is the difference?

Answer (score 4):

Your observation is reasonable: most of the time, `nextIndex` equals `matchIndex + 1`, but it is not always the case.

For example, when a leader is initiated, `matchIndex` is initiated to the 0, while `nextIndex` is initiated to the last log index + 1.

The difference here is because these two fields are used for different purposes: `matchIndex` is an accurate value indicating the index up to which all the log entries in leader and follower match. However, `nextIndex` is only an optimistic "guess" indicating which index the leader should try for the next AppendEntries operation, it can be a good guess (i.e. it equals `matchIndex + 1`) in which case the AppendEntries operation will succeed, but it can also be a bad guess (e.g. in the case when a leader was just initiated) in which case the AppendEntries will fail so that the leader will decrement `nextIndex` and retry.

As for `lastApplied`, it's simply another accurate value indicating the index up to which all the log entries in a follower have been applied to the underlying state machine. It's similar to `matchIndex` in that they both are both accurate values instead of heuristic "guess", but they really mean different things and serve for different purposes.

Answer (score 2):

> ... `lastApplied` is the highest log entry applied to state machine, but how is that any different than the `commitIndex`?

These are different in a practical system because the component that commits the data in the log is typically separate from the component that applies it to replicated state machine or database. The `commitIndex` is typically just nanoseconds or maybe a few milliseconds more up-to-date than `lastApplied`.

> Is the `matchIndex` on leader just the `commitIndex` on followers? If not what is the difference?

They are different. There is a period of time when the data is on a server and not yet committed, such as during the replication itself.

The leader keeps track of the latest un-committed data on each of its peers and only need to send `log[matchIndex[peer], ...]` to each peer instead of the whole log. This is especially useful if the peer is significantly behind the leader; because the leader can update the peer with a series of small `AppendEntries` calls, incrementally bringing the peer up to date.

Comment: big thanks for the answer, another quick question, is the information in `matchIndex` already captured in `nextIndex`? Since `nextIndex - 1 ` should be the `matchIndex`

Answer (score -1):

1. commit is not mean already applied, there is time different between them. but eventually applied will catch up commit index.
2. matchIndex[i] which is saved in leader is equal to follower_i's commitIndex, and they are try to catch up to nextIndex

Comment: No, `matchIndex[i]` is often **not** equal to follower `i`'s `commitIndex`. `matchIndex[i]` is the top index that has been replicated from leader to follower `i`. But there may be a majority of followers who haven't replicated that index yet, which means it's not yet committed. `commitIndex` (on leader, follower `i`, or both) may be much lower than `matchIndex[i]`.